# jqGrid with `multiselect: true` how can I make each row checked or not according to what the DB returns?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using jqGrid with `multiselect: true` how can I make each row checked or not according to what the DB returns?

I know that I can use on "loadcomplete" and loop though all elements that are already on the grid and checked them according to a hidden column value (or something like that.) However this is not what I am looking for (afterInsertRow is similar on the way that it is a "manualy" action to set the check value). I really need to set this checked or not while the grid "draws" the rows.

Is this possible?

Comment: what value are you wishing to check from the db to set the checkbox

Comment: Since I am not sure that what I want is possible, I am assuming that the "colModel" should have a property to set this bool value.

Comment: Can you please make your requirement clear. Is the database going to say some column as true false? On basis of which you wish the checkbox to be selected or not selected?? If so this can be done at the controller side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not enabled `gridview` option, then there is an event `afterInsertRow` available for handling:

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
    // code for selection here
    // example:
    $('selector for grid').jqgrid('setSelection', rowid);
},
```

More details in the documentation: [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) and [methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods).

**Update.** Other option is to define custom formatter for the column model. Assuming objects that are coming from DB contain property named `checked` that determines whether the row is selected, code might look something like this:

```
colModel:[
    {
        name:'checked',
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            if (cellvalue) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />';
            }
            return '<input type="checkbox" />';
        }
    },
    // rest of column models
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however it is not what I am looking forward, because using: afterInsertRow or loadComplete is exactly the same > manually setting the check value. Anyway I give you a thumbs up for the answer.

Comment: @Dryadwoods, well, maybe I misunderstood what you are looking for. Please see the updated post for yet another option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the template: "booleanCheckbox" property like below. , where available is the variable name from the backend.

```
{name:'available', hidden:false, width:30, sortable:true, search:false,
 template: "booleanCheckbox", resizable:false, formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
```